# Sinatra force logged in on controller

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a helper defined in `helpers/loggedin.rb` that has a function called `logged_in?` which checks if a user is logged in or not. is there any way I can call this at the top of a controller to force all views in that controller to redirect if the condition is not met or do I have to add the check to the dozens of views

controller currently looks something like this:

```
class ServiceController < ApplicationController
  ...
  get '/service/:id' do
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this if anyone else gets stuck.

```
before do
     redirect('/login') unless logged_in?
end
```

Please note that this will redirect **all** urls not just the ones explicitly defined in the controller